# Solr get collation document

Tags: php, solr, spell-checking

Can somebody of you tell me how to get the complete document from the collations suggestes from spellchecker. I cant find anything on google.

Must i query again with the collations the spellchecker offers me or can i configure the spellchecker to offer me the complete document as result?

THX

Answer (score 0):

You can get the document corresponding to corrected keyword by using spellcheck.collate and any fq parameters that are passed through to the original query while doing spellcheck will return results if the collation is re-run.

You need to re-run the query after getting back the corrected keyword..

You may also need to specify "spellcheck.maxCollationTries" with a value other than zero..This wil increase the probability..

http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SpellCheckComponent#spellcheck.collate